# jPlayer working with Rails app locally, but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, heroku, jplayer

I have the jPlayer audio player working fine locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, it no longer works and I get the following error in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jPlayer'
```

Here's the Javascript for jPlayer in my application.html.erb layout:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
      ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
             mp3: "http://test.com/song.mp3",
          // m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
          // oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
        });
      },
      swfPath: "/javascriptipts",
      supplied: "mp3, m4a, oga"
    });
  });
```

I'm noticing that the way the scripts are included seems to be working differently than it is on Heroku. For my local instance (which works) the scripts included look like this in the source:

```
   <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-responsive.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/calls.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/jplayer.blue.monday.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/main.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-button.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/calls.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/google-code-prettify/prettify.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.jplayer.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On Heroku, where jPlayer is not working, the scripts loaded look like this in the source for some reason:

```
<link href="/assets/application-7d9d2071282c290d4dd4bb767188d15f.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application-679ead39cc620e8b5be4723def8305ce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here's how I include them in my application.html.erb layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Anyone have any thoughts what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure that you deployed the assets correctly?

Comment: I'm not to be honest. I'm new to the asset pipeline. Right now I have everything in app/assets. I don't have anything in lib/assets or vendor/assets. Should I perhaps?

Comment: look into the compiled javascript if there is the javascript from the jplayer file

Comment: In my assets/application-679ead39cc620e8b5be4723def8305ce.js I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "Constructor" of undefined

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, though I'm not entirely sure why it was happening.

I had to remove the 'bootstrap-popover.js' file from 'assets/javascripts'. It was causing the following error locally (discussed above) which made me put 2-and-2 together.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "Constructor" of undefined
```

Not sure why it was working locally despite this error? If anyone knows, I'd love to learn why.